# Get code review status for a particular shelve set

Tags: shelveset

I am working on Build definition, where i have requirement to pull code review status for a particular shelve set. When i trigger a new Build with particular Shelve Set i need to check code review status is completed for that particular shelve set. Please provide me any code sample.